# New to Azure, using a student subscription and having trouble accessing some areas

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, entra

I have an Azure portal through a student account, where I have set up some VMs, VNs, disks etc. It doesn't help a bit that my textbook was written in 2019 and the instructions say to use Windows Server 2012 Datacenter which isn't on Marketplace anymore. (Yes I could take the ISO route but that wouldn't solve my current problem, which I think is in the Azure front end itself) The labs should be a breeze, there are step by step instructions to follow but the steps are not jiving with Azure as it is today. I made it through the first set of labs after much consternation. I have hit a wall with this weeks labs.

In trying to look at access control, users, security etc. in my Azure portal, I keep getting "No privileges, no permission, no access etc." This would include anything that is in Active Services (which is now "Entra" as I discovered.) I am the owner of the student account, and under subscription details, I am listed as Owner, and under roles "All".

Though there are Entra sections in my Azure portal (which wont let me even look at their settings) I tried to grab "Entra" from Azure Marketplace, but when I click on it even THAT tells me I don't have permission. One section in my Azure that I tried to access said I had no Admin role. (ok, besides the fact that I am "Owner", have "All" roles and should have Admin rights already, I can't GET to "Users" to create an Admin role if that would even help.)

So I can not access the sections I need to address the fact that I can't access the sections I need. Of course I emailed the professor of my somewhat underwhelming online learning facility two days ago but I haven't heard back.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!
Here are some examples of the messages I am getting:

You do not have access | Overview,Microsoft Entra ID
No access Summary
Session ID
809b9a9dcbde4fc78a8d4ac57601b120
Resource ID
Not available
Extension
Microsoft_AAD_IAM
Content
ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade
Error code
403

AND one more:

Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
Summary
Session ID
809b9a9dcbde4fc78a8d4ac57601b120
Resource ID
Not available
Extension
Microsoft_AAD_UsersAndTenants
Content
UserManagementMenuBlade
Error code
403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Owner role is an Azure RBAC role and does not apply to Azure AD / Entra ID.
This role should allow you to assign roles for resources and resource groups for example.

In order to manage users, you would need e.g. User Administrator role in the Entra ID tenant, which can only be given to you by an administrator in that tenant.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find a Microsoft support post about this as well. I found the email addresses of the Tenants under Show Roles in IAM, and I emailed them directly tonight. Hopefully they will give me what I need.